# SpringBoot: Failing at serialize Integer class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

there is a problem in serialization in a list of objects of a class that has an Integer attribute.

The exception is:

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

The class is: ***Discipline.java***

```
public class Discipline extends AbstractModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String course;

    private Integer teoricLoad;

    private Integer exerciseLoad;

    private Integer labLoad;

    // Ignored getters and setters
}
```

I checked the objects and the list of disciplines arent null just the Integer attributes.

Comment: how are you trying to serialize them?

Comment: @jpganz18 Auto serialize through annotation ResponseBody in controller mapping.

Comment: can you add more details about your problem, it's not clear. Are you using service and trying to call it?

Comment: Please post your setters/getters either, because jackson might be confused if your getter returns primitive int for your Integer fields, and no wonder it throws NPE then.

Comment: Mikhail Fedorov's guess was right! Yesterday's night I realized that my getter was returning primitive int, fixed and now everything are working well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just tell Jackson to ignore them by using:

`@JsonIgnoreProperties` at your class

or individually at the getter of each field you have this error with

```
@JsonIgnore
```

Comment: But I want it to write "null" string when value is null or merely not insert the key-value in conversion, because sometimes I need this attribute.
In another model it is done, but in Discipline model it isn't and I don't know why.